# How to deploy static content outside of war in root on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat

I have a docker container - Tomcat app (war file), which has its static content included in the war file. However for development purposes I would like to move the static content out of the war file and map it to a folder on the file system. The reason to do so is simple. I don't want to redeploy every time there is a change in a javascript file for example. I would like to reload the page in the browser and have the changes picked up. The Tomcat version is 8.

The most common solution to this problem (if you google it) is to change server.xml file and add a snippet similar to this one:

```
<Context docBase="/my/static/content/folder" path="/some/context" />
```

However I would like to map the static content to the root folder of my application. Say my war file name is myapp.war. It gets deployed under "/myapp". The problem is that if I want to add static content starting from root then my context snippet looks like this:

```
<Context docBase="/my/static/content/folder" path="/myapp" />
```

This is incorrect since the path must be unique and "myapp" can't be used by both - the automatic deployment which uses the war file name to derive the context and also the context snippet above. I could change path to point to "myapp/static" but then I will need to apply changes to the source code which I want to avoid.

Ideas how to map external folder to my application root are more than welcome.

Comment: why don't you create another docker image with a e.g. nginx httpd, serve the dev static content from that image and configure nginx to be a reverse proxy to your tomcat docker image?

Comment: For the time being I prefer to keep the set up as simple as possible. I could use Apache web server as well to serve the static content but I don't want to introduce another server for the time being. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

And answering my own question ...
the Context tag should look like:

```
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="myapp.war">
    <Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/my/static/content/folder"
            webAppMount="/">
        </PreResources>
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

One unpleasant side effect of this solution though is that my server startup time went up from ~22 seconds to ~52 seconds.
My "/my/static/content/folder" has 97 items and its size is 13.7MB.

Feedback how this could be improved or alternative solutions that do not have such big startup time are welcome.

UPDATE:
Switching from PreResources to PostResources solved the problem startup time. It went from ~52 seconds back to ~26 seconds. Now the overhead is only 4 seconds which is good enough for me.

UPDATE 2: In my original post I mentioned that the Context tag should be added to server.xml. This works but a better and cleaner way to add it is by creating a context.xml file and placing it under META-INF within the WAR file. This way the change is only in the WAR file and the server (respectively the Docker image) is the same regardless if it is used for development or not.